# Sorting AngularFireList<> with OrderByValue()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am trying to retrieve a list from firebase.
But not sure how to sort using orderByValue()

Referred the docs, but not sure why I need snapshot while sorting.

This is what I came up with using query.

My previous code :

```
private dbPath = '/articles';

articleRef: AngularFireList<Article> = null;

constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
   this.articleRef = db.list(this.dbPath);
 }

getArticlesList(): AngularFireList<Article> {
    return this.articleRef;
  }
```

What I tried doing :

```
getArticlesList(): AngularFireList<Article> {
  this.articleRef.query.orderByValue().on((a: Article, b: Article) => 
  b.votes - a.votes);
}
```

I get the following error:

(property) AngularFireList.query: firebase.database.Query
Expected 2-4 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)
index.d.ts(4546, 7): An argument for 'callback' was not provided.